# Cucumber: Before hook run only once for all scenarios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber

I have a scenario outline with multiple scenarios. I'd like my Before hook to run only once so I can bootstrap the ActiveRecord objects I need to run against all of the scenarios. The problem is if I use

```
Before do
    # my code here
end
```

This will execute before each Scenario. Is there anyway to run it once for the entire Outline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you simply create the objects in a file in *features/support* they will be persisted:

```
ImportantThing.create(:name => "USEFUL THING")
```

This is because before every Scenario Cucumber will start a database transaction and then rollback to its prior status, which should contain the objects you've loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, where I needed to create a subscriber manager once for all of my event logging tests. If I just used a before hook or a regular step (e.g. a Given), the manager would be created before each scenario.

My solution was ultimately to use a tagged before hook on my first scenario.

```
Before('@first_logging_scenario') do
  # do something useful
end
```

To shutdown my manager, I used  a tagged After hook with my last scenario

```
After('@last_logging_scenario') do
  # do something useful
end
```