# Adding a hook for object creation that only occurs once in Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I just need an object created once and only once in Cucumber.  I added a file in support/ called object_setup.rb and load it from within env.rb.  The file only contains:

@obj = SomeObj.new

But this object is not recognized within any of my steps.  The same thing happens if I add this line to the top of the steps file.

Comment: Same questions was asked here ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010987/cucumber-before-hook-run-only-once-for-all-scenarios

Comment: It's not the same question.  I did what the answer instructed by adding it to a file in the support folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use constants. For example put this into your env.rb

```
MY_AWESOME_OBJECT = SomeObj.new
```

It would be instantiated only once for all tests.

P.S: Or consider using singleton if it fits into your architecture.